# Can I put Up/Down Swipe GestureRecognizers on a vertical scrolling CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that scrolls vertically and I want to employ additional features on top of the scrolling when a vertical swipe is detected. Can I do this using gesture recognizers or do I have to hook into the `ScrollView` delegate and calculate swipe offsets?

I have tried adding a `GestureRecognizer` to the collection view and found that setting it to Left/Right invokes the delegate method, however, when I set it to up down the method is ignored. Is there simply an additional setting that I need to apply to either the gesture or the CollectionView, or is this approach not valid?

EDIT: I have added:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

However there seems to be some issue with the timing of the gestures. I amtrying to sift through the documentation now but the down swipe is only occasionally captured.

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the gesture and look at the functions available in the protocol?

Comment: Yes, in particular `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`, it seems like I am still missing something as my gesture recognizer method is not being invoked